# React Tabs inertiajs laravel

Tags: reactjs, laravel, inertiajs

I will be glad to get help with this. Anyone?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrpWw.png)

```
import React from "react";
{/* 
// @ts-ignore */}
import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid';
import { Tabs, TabsContent, TabsList, TabsTrigger } from "@/Components/Tabs";
import { Cross2Icon, PlusIcon } from "@radix-ui/react-icons"

interface Tab {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  content: any;
}

export function TabMenu(props: any) {
  const [tabs, setTabs] = React.useState<Tab[]>([
    { id: uuid(), name: "Index", content: props.content },
  ]);
  const [currentTab, setCurrentTab] = React.useState<Tab>({ id: uuid(), name: "Index", content: props.content });

  const handleAddTab = () => {
    const newTabObject: Tab = {
      id: uuid(),
      name: `Tab ${tabs.length + 1}`,
      content: props.content
    };

    setTabs([...tabs, newTabObject]);
    setCurrentTab(newTabObject);
  };

  const handleDeleteTab = (tabToDelete: Tab) => {
    const tabToDeleteIndex = tabs.findIndex((tab: Tab) => tab.id === tabToDelete.id);

    const updatedTabs = tabs.filter((tab: Tab, index: number) => {
      return index !== tabToDeleteIndex;
    });

    const previousTab = tabs[tabToDeleteIndex - 1] || tabs[tabToDeleteIndex + 1] || {};

    setTabs(updatedTabs);
    setCurrentTab(previousTab);
  };

  return (
      <div>
        <Tabs defaultValue="Index">
          <TabsList>
          <div className="flex flex-row space-x-2">
          {tabs.map((tab: Tab) => (
          <TabsTrigger key={tab.id} value={tab.name}>
              {tab.name}
              <button className="pl-1" onClick={() => handleDeleteTab(currentTab)}><Cross2Icon className="h-4 w-4" /></button>
          </TabsTrigger>
          ))}
          <button onClick={() => handleAddTab()}><PlusIcon className="h-4 w-4" /></button>
          </div>
          </TabsList>
            <div>
              {tabs.map((tab) => (
              <TabsContent key={tab.id} value={tab.name}>{tab.content}</TabsContent>
                ))}
            </div>
        </Tabs>
      </div>
  );
}
```

Im like to use route links to open new tabs via the tabs component.

```
<TabMenu content={children} />
```

Anyone?

I just wana have so i can link route to open new tab with the {children} content.

Im using react, inertiajs with laravel and hopes there is someone that can find a way to help me out here.

Thanks in advance